# Connect personal to organizational Account in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, account

We are using Microsoft Azure DevOps with personal accounts (with company mail-adress). We also use accounts created in corporate Azure-AD. That is, users have 2 accounts with the same email (personal and work).
How can I make the Azure Devops organization (created by a personal account) visible to Work accounts (created in an Azure-AD)?
I can add personal accounts to AD with different emails. But with the same emails, AD gives an error that such an account already exists in AD. How do I tell Azure-AD that I want to add a personal account?

Comment: I think that your problem is more conceptual than technical. Using the same email for personal and corporate accounts defeats the purpose of having "separates" accounts. That's the reason you have an error when you try to create the same account twice in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make the Azure Devops organization (created by a personal account) visible to Work accounts (created in an Azure-AD)?

I am afraid there is no such way to make the Azure Devops organization (created by a personal account) visible to Work accounts (created in an Azure-AD).

That because this is designed to separate personal and work accounts. Otherwise, we will be able to access Azure Devops organization at the same time using personal and work accounts. Obviously this is unreasonable. So I think there is no way to achieve your needs (at least for now).

To resolve this issue, we have to add personal accounts to AD with different email instead of the same email.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
If there is a mechanism for connecting guest accounts, then why can't you create a guest account with the same email? After all, Microsoft knows that there are several types of accounts, after all, you can add to the guest account by ID, for example.